# Which ports does az cli use?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to troubleshoot why az cli is consistently slow in one environment and fast in another. I think it's network related. Which ports does az cli use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, Port 443 (HTTPS) as AZ CLI is simply a wrapper over [`Azure REST API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).